# Minimum of random walks

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, random-walks

Let $M$ independent and identical random walks that follow the chi-squared distribution, i.e. in each step, a $X^2_1$ random variable is added. I am interested in the minimum random walk at each step. Is it possible to directly model a random walk that is the minimum of $M$ random walks as a function of $M$ without sampling?

In the following figure, $M = 64$ and the bold red line is the minimum.

[image]

Comment: Since the random walks $S_{n}^{i},i=1,..,M$ are independent, then you can even get the cdf: 

$$F(t)=1-P(\min_{i=1,..,M} S_{n}^{i}>t)=1-\prod_{i=1}^{M}P(S_{n}^{i}\geq t).$$

So now that you have the CDF, you can use quantiles to generate it, that is the uniform distribution in [0,1]: $P(U\leq F(t))=F(t)$. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460767/intuition-behind-generating-discrete-random-variables-from-a-uniform-random-numb

Comment: @ThomasKojar : This way, one can only simulate the one-dimensional distributions of the minimum of the random walks, rather than the distribution of the entire minimum process.

Comment: Yes, I realized that but seems much tougher due to the non-Markovian structure. Some work on the max and simulations are here: "Record Statistics for Multiple Random Walks" http://lptms.u-psud.fr/ressources/publis/2012/Record%20statistics%20for%20multiple%20random%20walks.pdf

Comment: @ThomasKojar : Thank you for the reference. I would be greatly surprised if the answer to the posted question is positive. On the other hand, it seems next to impossible to provide a formal proof for the negative answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I think I have something: In step $n$ we can use the minimum $V_{n-1}$ of step $n-1$ to condition $M-1$ iid rvs $P(Y_i = X^2_{n-1} + X^2_1|X^2_{n-1} \geq V_{n-1})$ for $1 \leq i \leq M-1$. Additionally, $A = V_{n-1}+X^2_1$.  Let the cdf of Y $F_{Y}$, then the cdf of the $B = min(Y_1,...Y_{M-1})$ is $F_B = 1-(1-F_{Y})^{M-1}$. So we can produce directly Β and with one comparison $V_{n} = min(A,B)$. Is that ok? @IosifPinelis

Comment: @IoannisPapoutsidakis : I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you for responding. The problem I am trying to solve is mostly about the complexity of the computation because $M$ grows exponentially in my application. So in the previous comment, I describe a recursive algorithm to reduce the comparisons - to produce a random minimum $V_n$ at step $n$ - from $M-1$ to 1 using the minimum $V_{n-1}$ of the previous step. Is there something specific I need to clarify?

Comment: @IoannisPapoutsidakis : Try to define everything formally and completely. Maybe, I will then be able to understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S^i_n=X_{i,1}+...+X_{i,n}$ be the value of $i$-th random walk at time $n$, where $i=1,2,...,M$. Assuming that $X_{i,s}\sim\chi^2(k)$ distributed and independent for some $k>0$, we get that $S_t^i\sim\Gamma\left(\frac{kn}2,\frac12\right)$ distributed. Hence
$$
\tilde S_n:=\min_{i=1,2,...,M} S_n^i
$$
and so
$$
{\mathbb P}(\tilde S_n>a)=\left[\int_a^{\infty} \frac{x^{kn/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{2^{kn/2}} dx\right]^n
=\left[\int_{a/2}^{\infty}  y^{kn/2-1} e^{-y} dy\right]^n
$$
Of course, $\tilde S_n,n=1,2,...,$ is not  a ``random walk" in the usual sence, as it's not a Markov chain.

Comment: This way, one can only simulate the one-dimensional distributions of the minimum of the random walks, rather than the distribution of the entire minimum process.